# Can you create HttpClient read-only property and re-use it in your methods?

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly, dotnet-httpclient, httpclientfactory

Is there any issue with below implementation inside Blazor component? A lot of examples repeatedly use `CreateClient` inside every method and I am wondering if it can be handled by a property, in one place to avoid repetition.

```
@inject IHttpClientFactory ClientFactory

@code{
    private HttpClient Client => ClientFactory.CreateClient("api");
    private object myData;

    private async Task GetData()
    {
        myData = await Client.GetFromJsonAsync<MyClass>("endpoint");
    }
}
```

Comment: "Is there any issue with below implementation inside Blazor component?" From a design standpoint, you're piling all your data access into your component.  Your component has lots of responsibilities.  It's getting the data, managing the data and displaying the data: there's no "Separation of Concerns."    If you're Ok with that, continue.

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis how instead should I write component that displays data from the api?

Comment: @Pawel - ideally move the code to access the API into a typed HttpClient (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/implement-resilient-applications/use-httpclientfactory-to-implement-resilient-http-requests#implement-your-typed-client-classes-that-use-the-injected-and-configured-httpclient ... Then that typed client can hide the API access and deserialization into required types, e.g. `MyClass`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is fine.

The `HttpClientFactory` will take care of disposal of `HttpMessageHandler`s.

The `=>` syntax essentially means that you've created an Alias (left-hand side) for running code (right-hand side).

In other words, you ARE calling CreateClient inside every method, except you've made your life a little easier by using an Alias `Client`.